# How to get from Venice to Rijeka, Croatia by sea?

Tags: italy, ferries, croatia, venice

I want to travel from Venice to Rijeka, Croatia by ferry. We will be there in July. Is this possible, or do we need to stop at Pula and take a bus? Is there a website that can help me?

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions! We want to travel on July 2, a Saturday. I can't tell what ferry to take on a Saturday.

Answer (score 2):

The best choice (if you want to travel only by boat) would be to travel by ferry to Rabac from Venice, then rent a "[taxiboat](https://www.kroati.de/kroatien-infos/bootsverleih-taxiboot-rabac.html)" to Rijeka. Otherwise you need to travel to Pula and find something like that there. Moneywise I would say that the least expensive way to get to Rijeka is to take the ferry to Pula and then a bus from there.

Mine are just speculations... Normally a ferry between 2 big cities (Venice and Pula) should be cheaper (and more frequent) than a ferry between a big city and a smaller one. Also consider that Rijeka is farther than Pula, so I'm betting it costs more.
Also consider that bus lines have scheduled trips and can count on a plethora of customers (cheaper), but a taxiboat works "on demand" with only a few passengers (expensive)...

I cannot give a quote on prices, since they depend on the lines you are using, the days you are travelling and so on.

Comment: Could you add a quote with the costs of all the options?

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

[Rome2Rio suggests taking the ferry to Pula, and from there a bus to Rijeka.](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Venice/Rijeka) Below is a screenshot from Rome2Rio:

[image: Rome2Rio Pula to Rijeka]

[The buses are operated by Autotrans.](https://www.autotrans.hr/en-us/home) They run approximately every 2-3 hours, and takes 2h20m to get to Rijeka. At the time of writing (Feb. 2016) the price for a one-way ticket is 86 HRK. Below is a sample timetable for buses leaving on the 13/07/2016:

[image: Pula to Rijeka autotrans bus timetable and price]